# Javascript, Use a regex to replace content outside of HTML tags only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript to replace strings that are outside of HTML tags, and to ignore the strings within HTML tags.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var content = "Hi, my <span user="John">name</span> is &nbsp;John";
var user = 'John';
var regex = new RegExp('(&nbsp;)?' + user,'g');
content.replace(regex, function($0,$1){
    return $1 ? $0 : '<img src="images/user.png">';
});
```

My regex is `"(&nbsp;)?John"`.

The pattern works the way I want to, but it applies the matching to tag data, which I don't want.

So, the idea is to ignore everything between tags: `<` and `>`, and to ignore: `&nbsp;John`.

Can it be done?

Comment: [Look what I found in the related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1). You should probably try to create a DOM from your input string and then iterate over text-nodes only.

Comment: @m.buettner is right; regex is not the right tool to parse html. it's really easy to parse a string into dom nodes if you use a javascript library though—for example, jquery has a great parse function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: I see you want to replace every occurrence of the word `John` with an image, except those that are inside attributes. Is that right? Or is it required that, in addition, a `&nbsp;` precedes the word `John` (like `#` is the hashtag for twitter)?

Comment: @acdcjunior he replaces all text-instances that are not preceded by `&nbsp;`

Comment: Filip, can you provide some desired output to match your sample text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This regex will match `John` providing it is either at the start or end of the string and/or has white space on either side.

Regex to match John: `(?:\s|&nbsp;|^)(John)(?=\s|\r|\n|$)`

This regex incorporates that last regex and also matches all html tags and plain text urls. The order here is important because `John` will only match providing it's outside an html tag or not embeded into a URL.

Regex: `https?:\/\/[^\s]*|<\/?\w+\b(?=\s|>)(?:='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*|[^>])*>|\&nbsp;John|(John)`

If you take this last regex and pass it through your function, then only `John`s outside the tags & urls will be replaced with a string.

## Javascript Example

Working example: http://repl.it/J4T

**Code**

```
var content = "<span name=\"John\" funnytag:John>John John &nbsp;John DoeJohn JohnDoe Mr.JohnDoe http://cool.guy.john/LikesKittens</span>";
var rePattern = /https?:\/\/[^\s]*|<\/?\w+\b(?=\s|>)(?:='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*|[^>])*>|\&nbsp;John|(John)/gi;

content.replace(rePattern, function(match, capture) {
    return capture ? "<img src=\"images/user.png\">" : match;
});
```

**Output**

`<span name="John" funnytag:John><img src="images/user.png"> <img src="images/user.png"> &nbsp;John Doe<img src="images/user.png"> <img src="images/user.png">Doe Mr.<img src="images/user.png">Doe http://cool.guy.john/LikesKittens</span>`

Comment: Works almost great :). One problem is that John is replaced only if it is surrounded with spaces. E.g. `<b>John` or `JohnDoe` are not replaced. Another problem is that when I have " John" or `&nbsp;John`, the replacement image removes the space in front of John. And one more thing, "&nbsp;John" should remain the same as it is. The example I gave in the question was replacing every "John" except the one that was starting with `&nbsp;` and the idea was to continue with the same pattern, plus ignoring John in tags. I would fix it by myself, but it is too complex expression for my knowledge.

Comment: Updated to cover your examples.

Comment: What is this sorcery?

Comment: I can't get over how wonderful this is. It works perfect. Your a wizard Denomales. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're saying that you want to replace anything matching the regex as long as it's not contained within a tag, i.e. **John** and optionally a preceding non-breaking space would be replaced with the return value of `function($0,$1)` *unless* it appears inside an HTML tag?

If so, you could add this look-behind assertion to the beginning of your regex: `(?<!<[^>]*?)`. That tells the regex to match the pattern if reading backwards from the match it doesn't encounter a **<** before it encounters a **>**.

This would be your code:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?<!<[^>]*?)(&nbsp;)?' + user,'g');
```

Comment: Javascript does not support lookbehinds