# RegEx not working in Javascript: SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a RegEx that can single out words from a string but ignore them if they're inside a tag. For example: Even though the searchword is SPAN, do not replace a span tag.

What I have so far is:

```
(?<![<\/])\bspan\b(?!>)
```

http://regex101.com/r/vS6yG6

Span obviously is a placeholder. In the script it is generated from a dictionary dynamically.

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
var reg = new RegExp(the expression, 'gi');
```

I've escaped the /, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

And this is what I get back: `SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier`

Any help would be appreciated. I made the Regular Expression with the help of regex101.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace content while ignoring tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373919/replace-content-while-ignoring-tags)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactelly what I'm doing. but 'span' is added in a loop. I use the expression from the link but escaped '/'.

Comment: Negative LookBehind does not exist in javascript. [There are workarounds](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

Comment: Oh it's that simple? Too bad. Okay, I'll look at the workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David replied, there is no Negative LookBehind in Javascript, so that's where the problem was.

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
/>[^<>]*\b(span)\b[^<>]*<?/ig
```

Comment: Nope, that selects half the string.